# Content's padding-top based on fixed header's height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a layout using fixed `header`, with a main `nav` and another nav called `#sub_nav`. The thing is the #sub_nav got many items to choose, so when I reduce the width of the browser, the last item breaks the line, and a portion of the content hides behind the flexible header.

Here's an illustration:
[image: illustration]

### And here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arkl1te/GjdUz/1/)

I wonder if there's a CSS / JS solution for that. I also accept jquery solutions.

Apologise if the image is annoying but I hope you understand what do I want to solve.

Comment: you need to change position:absoulte; of your #sub_nav to position:relative;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[UPDATED]**
Because the header is fixed, it overlaps on top of the main contents. You need to use jquery to increase the top padding of your #mid when #sub_nav height gets greater than it's actual height. Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var subNav = $("#sub_nav");
    var main = $("#mid");

    if(subNav.height() > 25){
        main.css({"padding-top": "220px"});
    }
    else{
        main.css({"padding-top": "190px"});
    }
    $(window).resize(function(){

        if(subNav.height() > 25){
            main.css({"padding-top": "220px"});
        }
        else{
            main.css({"padding-top": "190px"});
        }

    }); 

});
```

Comment: You don't need to use dollar signs, but make sure you use same variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `header` be fixed (or absolutely) positioned AND have the `div#mid` element be positioned relative to it with the wrapping content from the header pushing it down.

I would suggest reducing the words in the subnav links if possible.  From a design stand-point, it looks bad and it's bad UX to be as hard to read as it is.  You can also try a responsive layout where if the browser width gets too narrow, you change the design of the menu.